# Set static variable from Gradle on build-time

Tags: java, android, git, android-studio, gradle

I've got an Android project, managed under git. 
Git has 2 branches (well more.. but important are those two), branch-a & branch-b. 
Is it possible to set up gradle to determine which branch was the project built from and set up the `public static String` in one of the project's classes to value depending on the branch?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you may have a `gradle.properties` file in both your branches (you can read about properties [here](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_environment.html)), containig some property, for example `buildBranchName`. But the value assigned to this property will differ in every brach. For example, in brach1 you have a gradle.properties file in the same directory as your build.gradle script and it has a

```
buildBranchName=branch1
```

property inside. At the same time, gradle.properties file in branch2 contains:

```
buildBranchName=branch2
```

Then, since you have an android project, you can use a `BuildConfig` class generation option to pass this variable into you application sources. You can read about it [here](http://toastdroid.com/2014/03/28/customizing-your-build-with-gradle/), in "Enhancing your BuildConfig" section. All you need, is to add some property to this autogenerated class for your build types, just like:

```
android {
    ...
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            buildConfigField "String", "BUILD_BRANCH", buildBranchName
        }
        ...
    }    
}
```

Then, during the build, the final class `BuildConfig` will be generated and it will have a `BUILD_BRANCH` field, which you may use as a simple static field of this class.

Furthermore, if some has a non-android project, there is a [plugin](https://github.com/mfuerstenau/gradle-buildconfig-plugin), which allows to do the same for all java-projects.

Comment: Stanislav, little edit: I can get git branch in build.gradle like this: https://paste.kde.org/ppnxzmgpk , which seems to be a much better solution. I didn't know about buildConfigField, which makes this job done. Thank you!

Comment: @MikhailKrutov yep, you can do it via exec-type task, but IMO, sometimes this is not the best solution, since it relies on command line call of remote process and doesn't provide a fixed list of brach names. But yes, mostly it relies on requirements. Just for example, I have something similar, but with a large amount of branches for different versions and customers. In properties we have a customer name, which is the same for a number of braches and the names are stored as a fixed and doesn't rely on a branch name

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can do this by adding the flavours to the project

e.g.

```
    android {
     ......

    productFlavors {
        branch1 {
            buildConfigField("String", "WHICH_BRANCH", "Branch1")
        }
        branch2 {
            buildConfigField("String", "WHICH_BRANCH", "Branch2")
        }
    }
    .........
}
```

Now to access this value like this

e.g.

```
 String whichBranch = BuildConfig.WHICH_BRANCH;
```

Let me know in case of any issues