# Jenkins breaks build logic by executing "git checkout -f revision", how to disable this behaviour?

Tags: java, git, jenkins

I got new buildConfig today, with help of this question:

[Set static variable from Gradle on build-time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34083281/set-static-variable-from-gradle-on-build-time)

The problem is, that when I run `commandLine 'git', 'rev-parse', '--abbrev-ref', 'HEAD'` on jenkins-cloned repository, in which jenkins executes `git checkout -f <revision>`, the build breaks in unusual way: 
`buildConfigField "String", "BUILD_BRANCH", getBranchName().toString()` becomes set to `HEAD` (not even `"HEAD"`), so I get:
`error: cannot find symbol
  public static final String BUILD_BRANCH = HEAD;`

I've tried to google around with this issue, but didn't find anything. How do I disable additional checking out of exact revision by Jenkins? Is it possible?

Additionally, I'd be happy to know why does Jenkins do that?

This can be solved, of course, by having separate `build.gradle` in each branch, but for some reason I'd like to avoid that.

Comment: Just to note, you can modify it to `buildConfigField "String", "BUILD_BRANCH", '"' + getBranchName() + '"'`. By adding a double quotes and removing `toString()`, since it's a String already

Comment: Stanislav, strange thing is that.. Build on my local machine works as expected even after git checkout -f <revision>; just the constant is "HEAD" in this case, but jenkins (or something that I didn't discover that jenkins does) breaks that, and build runs w/ removed "'s. This is, however, fixed with your original suggestion of having different build.gradle in each branch, which is well clear & fine enough.